# How can i install Debian without using the install gui?

Tags: debian, system-installation

So, I've got several debian install disks, but i'm attempting to install it on a qemu virtual machine, using curses as the graphical output. The issue i'm having is that curses doesn't do very well with graphical interfaces, and since the debian boot disks boot directly into a gui, all i get is a black screen on startup.

Is there any way to install using a cli instead of a gui? Just hitting a few hotkeys and getting a cli would be ideal.

Comment: Hrm... when I boot Debian it gives me a choice of graphical install or text-based ncurses install... do you not get the boot menu?

Comment: no, i don't get the boot menu in curses. I know i can hit 'esc' and get a command prompt, but i don't know what command to use to get a non-graphical install.

Comment: Are you putting the debian iso as the boot iso for qemu? That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, you can press escape once the disk boots, and you'll get a command prompt. Then you can just start the install with specific flags and it'll do the install completely in cli.

```
install vga=false fb=false
```